# Error insert laravel (String Conversion)

Tags: laravel, array, insert

estoy insertando un array a mi tabla de mi bd pero al enviar me sale un error, el cual es el siguiente:

> Array to string conversion

nose cual es es el problema que sucede, saben cual es el problema?, adjunto codigo para que me puedan ayudar

```js
public function storeHorario(Request $request) {
  $clase = $request -> clase;
  $fecha_clase = $request -> fecha_clase;
  $hora_clase = $request -> hora_clase;
  $duracion_clase = $request -> duracion_clase;
  $profesor = $request -> profesor;



  $horario = DB::table('horario') -> insertGetId(
    ['clase_nombre' => $clase,
      'fecha' => $fecha_clase,
      'hora' => $hora_clase,
      'id_bloque' => $duracion_clase,
      'id_user' => $profesor
    ]);

    $message = array(
      'message' => 'Su horario ha sido agregado con exito',
      'type' => 'success'
    );
    return redirect() -> back() -> with($message);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
return redirect()->back()->with($message)
```

No es correcto y es ahí donde te da el error. Modifícalo de esta forma:

```
return redirect()->back()->with(['message',$message]);
```

En Blade:

```
@if (Session::has('message'))
<div class="alert alert-success">
   {{Session::get('message')}}
</div>
@endif
```

Comment: @Matias Si te sirvió la respuesta, por favor márcala como aceptada. Así otros usuarios que tengan el mismo problema podrán guiarse mejor. Gracias

Comment: perdon, me quede dormido anoche, aun asi, con tu respuesta, no me funciono aun tengo el error Array To String conversion

Comment: @Matias He creado un proyecto nuevo y he probado el código tal como lo tienes y funciona perfectamente. Prueba con los comandos `php artisan config:clear`, `php artisan view:clear`, `php artisan cache:clear` y por último `composer dumpautoload`.

Comment: ya solucione el problema, ese codigo no me sirvio tuve que ocupar otro, lo subo como respuesta

Answer (score 0):

**

### SOLUCION

**

```js
public function storeHorario(Request $request)
   {

    $id_curso = $request->id_curso; 
    $clase = $request->clase;
    $fecha_clase = $request->fecha_clase;
    $hora_clase = $request->hora_clase;
    $duracion_clase = $request->duracion_clase;
    $profesor = $request->profesor;


    for ($count = 0; $count<count($clase); $count++){
        $horario = array(
            'clase_nombre' => $clase[$count],
             'fecha'=>$fecha_clase[$count],
             'hora'=>$hora_clase[$count],
             'id_bloque'=>$duracion_clase[$count],
             'id_user'=>$profesor[$count]
            );
        $insertHorario[] = $horario;
    }
    $horarioSync->horario()->sync($id_curso);
    Horario::insert($insertHorario);


    $message= array(
                    'message' => 'Su horario ha sido agregado con exito',
                    'type' => 'success'
                );
    return redirect()->back()->with(['message',$message]);
   }
```

Comment: Procura por favor explicarla, ya eres usuario de tiempo y sabes lo esperado en las respuestas. Saludos

Comment: Lo siento, respondi rapido que no tenia tiempo, lo explico cuando tenga disponibilidad de tiempo